# How do I work menuLibre in Xubuntu 14.04 & 14.10?

Tags: xubuntu, menu

The askUbuntu's suggested previous questions don't address my question(s).  So, ....
I haven't seen how to order menu items in Xubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 in/with menuLibre.  I found instructions for using it, but the ones for ordering menu items didn't and don't work.  The instructions I found said that my problems were known issues, that they'd be repaired in the 14.10 version, and that soon after there would be a repaired version available for download into 14.04.  Well, none of that has come to pass.  Can someone tell me how to order Xubuntu's displayed menu items?

I did, finally, manage to get a few items listed that came with Xubuntu but didn't show up in its menu, but it was a royal pain.  It took half a dozen steps just to get each item displayed in Xubuntu's menu.  The same task was a single, simple mouse click in alacarte (checking a checkbox).  The problem with alacarte is that it installs as root.  Great, another possible malware vector.  Of course, I could install alacarte, make the changes I want, then remove it.  But this computer is for a friend whom I won't have that much contact with, so I'd like to have a menu-editing program installed that either I can use or that I can direct her to use--if it isn't too big a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal

$ menulibre

Highlight item to be moved.

Click on up or down arrow in lower left hand corner.

Lather, Rinse, Repeat

I just installed 14.04 (with updates) about 4 am today. The version of menulibre that you want DOES exist. Might want to uninstall the version you have before installing the new one "just in case".